# Django file upload without model and posted using ajax

Tags: django

How to save a file, uploaded from a form to a local directory without using model? Also the form is being posted using ajax, so how do I render the file information from the html file?

Comment: Those are two different questions, and you're trying to ask them in one. Anyways, for uploading filea via AJAX, check out jQuery-form plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTML form with

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="your_view_name">
    <input name="myfile" type="file" />
</form>
```

Use AJAX to post the file. If you're using jQuery, see this link on how to post stuff

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

In the view, use `request.FILES` to access the uploaded file. Use whatever Python APIs you have to save the file to the disk.